# How to make other test cases to wait for some time till a test case performs an action in TestNG parallel execution

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am running my test cases in parallel. Many times, I am getting problem in choosing values from react dropdown. Suppose, I had to choose a value from react dropdown, I had to perform 2 operations:
1. Click on the dropdown button.
2. Choose the value from the dropdown.

Sometimes, during parallel execution, after performing the first step, the next thread is running hence window is switched. When it switch back to the first window and perform the second step, dropdown was no more present, so test case is failing.

The dropdown looks like this:

[image]

Is there anyway I shall make other threads to wait for some time, till this thread performs the action?

***What I tried?***
**Try 1:**
In many places they said, we can't pause a thread from another thread. But still, I tried with this. All the TestNG thread seem to have name containing 'TestNG', so I used that to identify it. Then added one more condition that if this thread's id is not same as my thread's id, I can make it wait.

```
public void stopThisThread(long threadId) throws Throwable{
        synchronized(this) {
            System.out.println("Stop other threads called...");
            Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
            try {           
                for(Thread t : threadSet) {
                    System.out.println("Inside loop : " + printThread(t));
                    if(t.getName().contains("TestNG") && t.getId()!=threadId) {
                        t.wait();
                        System.out.println("Wait is called on " + t.getId());
                    }
                }
            }catch(Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

As expected, it didn't work. It threw `java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException`
**Try 2**
I thought like, instead of calling wait from another thread, why don't we call wait from the same thread and then later let it resume operation. So, here test2 is going to choose value from dropdown. So, I made the test1 thread to wait. Once the test2 is done with the job, I thought to call 'notify' to make test1 resume its operation. It also didn't work.

```
@Test
public synchronized void test1() throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("test1 - " + printThread(Thread.currentThread()));       
    int i = 0;
    while(true) {           
        System.out.println("test1");
        if(i == 0)
            Thread.currentThread().wait();
        Thread.sleep(2000);         
    }
}

@Test
public synchronized void test2() throws Exception{
    System.out.println("test2 - " + printThread(Thread.currentThread()));
    int i = 0;
    while(true) {
        System.out.println("test2");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        if(++i == 5)
            Thread.currentThread().notifyAll();
    }
}
```

This is throwing `java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException` on both the test cases.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ilya Thanks for the answer. I don't want to but I have to. I checked with other options. Finally found `join`

```
@Test
public void test1() throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("test1 - " + printThread(Thread.currentThread()));               
    while(true) {           
        System.out.println("test1");            
        Thread.sleep(2000);         
        i++;            
    }
}

@Test
public void test2() throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("test2 - " + printThread(Thread.currentThread()));   
    int j = 0;
    while(true) {
        System.out.println("test2");
        if(j==0)
            Thread.currentThread().join(10000);
        Thread.sleep(2000); 
        j++;
    }
}

@Test
public void test3() throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("test3 - " + printThread(Thread.currentThread()));   
    int j = 0;
    while(true) {
        System.out.println("test3");
        if(j==0)
            Thread.currentThread().join(10000);
        Thread.sleep(2000); 
        j++;
    }
}
```

The output came as:

```
test2 - 14 - TestNG-test=test-2 - false
test2
test3 - 15 - TestNG-test=test-3 - false
test3
test1 - 13 - TestNG-test=test-1 - false
test1
test1
test1
test1
test1
test1
test3
test2
test1
test3
test2
test1
```

In the same way I have modified my project. Am now able to choose dropdown value without any hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Support thread management too difficult task and you will get a lot of problems with it.

**Keep your tests as independent as possible.**

To run tests in parallel you could use a tool like [Selenoid](https://aerokube.com/selenoid/latest/). Tune it once and you will have a good environment to launch your tests.

I think it will help you.